# Table in JSON format sent by Flask reaches JQuery with escaping backward slashes and JQuery fails to parse

Tags: python, jquery, pandas, datatables-1.10, flask-socketio

- I have Python App running with Flask-Socketio that emits a Pandas dataframe. The dataframe gets emitted to the client JQuery Data.Tables. For some reason, the dataframe's contents in json format get backslashed/escaped.

Python Code:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
import socketio

Boxes = [{'Color':'Green','Color':'Green','Color':'Green'},{'Shape':'Square','Shape':'Square','Shape':'Rectangle'}]
df = DataFrame(Boxes,columns=['Color','Shape'])
df2 = df.to_json(orient='columns')
print(df2)
socketio.emit('tableMessage',{'theTable':df2},namespace='/test')
socketio.sleep(7)
```

Dataframe printed from Python :

```
{"Color":{"0":"Blue","1":"Red","2":"Red","3":"Red"},"Shape":{"0":"Square","1":"Square","2":"Square","3":"Rectangle"}}
```

Javascript - JQuery Code:

```
socket.on('tableMessage', function(msg) {

        $('#table2').DataTable({

            data: msg.theTable,

            columns: [
            { title: "Color" },
            { title: "Shape" },
            ],
        });
    });
```

Dataframe emitted displayed by the server console:

```
Sending packet MESSAGE data 2/test,["tableMessage",{"theTable":"{\"Color\":{\"0\":\"Blue\",\"1\":\"Red\",\"2\":\"Red\",\"3\":\"Red\"},\"Shape\":{\"0\":\"Square\",\"1\":\"Square\",\"2\":\"Square\",\"3\":\"Rectangle\"}}"}]
```

Does anybody know how to get this displayed properly as a table in Jquery?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I used 
   `df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Green','Tree'],['Yellow','Pyramid'],['Red','Circle'],['White','Ball']])` 
   in creating the Python dataframe.
2. df2 = df.to_json(orient='records') 
   to convert the dataframe to JSON object.
3. '

```js
socket.on('tableMessage', function(msg) {
        alert(msg.theTable);
        var someObject = JSON.parse(msg.theTable);
        $('#table2').DataTable({
            
            "searching": false,
            "ordering": false,
            "paging": false,
            "bordering":true,
            data: someObject,
            columns: [
            {"title": 'Color'},
            {"title": 'Shape'},
            ]

        });
    });
```

'

To parse the table in JQuery.
 4.

```html
    <div class="container" id="content">
        <p>This is table</p>
        <table id="table2" class="display" width="25%" margin-left=10%>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Color</th>
                    <th>Shape</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

To display in html.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse JSON before providing it as data to `DataTables`. Something like this:

```
socket.on('tableMessage', function(msg) {

        $('#table2').DataTable({

            data: JSON.parse(msg.theTable),

            columns: [
            { title: "Color" },
            { title: "Shape" },
            ],
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey. JSON.parse() did not do it. I added an alert message to JQuery code, and it displayed the table JSON string without any backslashes but it displays the following error "DataTables warning: table id=table2 - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4". I do not understand what this error message is saying in this context since the table data is well defined and present in the cells.